# R: Accessing "start" attribute of "msts" object

Tags: r, attributes

I've created an `msts` object like this:

```
y <- msts(1:100, start=c(1,4), ts.frequency=6, seasonal.periods=c(6,12,50))
```

When called, it shows its contents, including the `start` parameter:

```
> head(y)
Multi-Seasonal Time Series:
Start: 1 4
Seasonal Periods: 6 12 50
Data:
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

However, `start` cannot be seen as an attribute:

```
> attributes(y)
$tsp
[1]  1.5 18.0  6.0

$class
[1] "msts" "ts"  

$msts
[1]  6 12 50
```

My question is, how can I get the `start` vector `c(1,4)` stored inside `y`?

Comment: try: `start(y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?msts` reveals that the start parameter is an attribute of the `ts` class

> Arguments to be passed to the underlying call to ts(). For example start=c(1987,5).

The "See Also" section of `?ts` mentions print methods for the `ts` object. `start` is one of them.

This seems to give you what you want:

```
> library(forecast)
> y <- msts(1:100, start=c(1,4), ts.frequency=6, seasonal.periods=c(6,12,50))
> start(y)
[1] 1 4
```

Comment: Wow, print methods! That's really great, thank you for your answer!